# Magento 2: Load patches or update

Tags: magento2, upgrade, security, patches

I'm aware that this probably isn't the first time this question has been answered, but I'm wondering what is the best approach to keeping my magento 2.3.1 install secure: Should I update to 2.3.2 or install patches?

How risky is it to update Magento between minor versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to update to the new version on your **staging environment**, run the regression. If everything turns out fine, roll out the new version in production.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. Do you have any experience in updating magento and how well it works / doesn't work?

Comment: @nanos, it depends on the 3rd party modules you are using, if all you are using is shipped by Magento, then it won't be a huge effort. Give it a try, will be good for your experience.